# NoMethodError: undefined method `pages' for # Array when use as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I know that this is a answered question, but today as I setup a simple map over a array this issue comes again!

the map unlike the common way to do it is using `as_json`

```
 def index
    @allcomments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc')
    .includes(:user,:replies).paginate page: params[:page]

    @comments = @allcomments.map do |comment|
      comment_json = comment.as_json
      comment_json[:user] = comment.user.as_json
      comment_json[:replies] = comment.replies.as_json
      comment_json
    end

    render json: {
      comments: @comments.paginate(page: page),
      page: page,
      pages: @comments.pages,
      status: 200
    }
  end
```

As the answer should be place `require 'will_paginate/array'` on the initializer, I did, or on the `ApplicationController`, I did too, or on the comments controller I did it too!

So, someone has any clue about this particular issue with `will_paginate`?

Comment: It looks like there's an extra `=` in here before `comment_json[:replies]` which does an inadvertent chain assignment.

Comment: Normally for things like that you put them in `config/initializers` like `will_paginate.rb` would be the expected file there.

Comment: @tadman thank you and i placed the require on the initializer and still this NoMethodError: undefined method `pages' for # Array! so this is related to the map somehow?

can you test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply `map` you yield a raw array which loses the pagination features. You need to preserve that.

One thing you could do here to fix this is to write a `as_json` method for Comment that properly implements the logic you have in that `map`, handling the `user` and `replies` encoding correctly. The goal here is to get rid of that step in the controller, move that to the model where it belongs.

Then this becomes:

```
@comments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc')
  .includes(:user,:replies).paginate(page: params[:page])

paginated = @comments.paginate(page: page)

render(json: {
  comments: paginated,
  page: page,
  pages: paginated.pages,
  status: 200
})
```